# Firebase Android Studio (2.2.3) issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am facing a problem to compile Firebase in my android project.Here is my app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my_app_id>"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the build gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am getting an error of **Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using android studio,

Goto tools -> Firebase

And follow on screen instructions. Android studio take care of the dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

update your play service version and also update firebase dependency version.